# How to Create an Action Method invoking two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Thanks in advance for your help. I cannot move forward creating or editing fields in asp.net mvc using two tables or more. As an example: I´ve been using MVC Music Store example to learn

```
//
// GET: /StoreManager/Create

public ActionResult Create()
{
    var viewModel = new StoreManagerViewModel
    {
       Album = new Album(),
       Genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList(),
       Artists = storeDB.Artists.ToList()
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}

//
// POST: /StoreManager/Create

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(Album album) 
  {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        //Save Album
        storeDB.AddToAlbums(album);
        storeDB.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }

   // Invalid – redisplay with errors
   var viewModel = new StoreManagerViewModel
   {
      Album = album,
      Genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList(),
      Artists = storeDB.Artists.ToList()
   };
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

This example takes into consideration that Album is only one table at the model. My main question resides in the way I have to code in order to include another table with FK to Album. As an example if AlbumVariant table - eg: field albumid- displays a FK to Album Table - eg: field albumid-.

I´ve been trying with

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
   var albumCreate= db.Album.Include(AlbumVariant)SingleOrDefault(a => a.AlbumId == id);
   var viewModel = new AlbumViewModelCreate()
   {
      AlbumCreate = albumCreate,
   };
}
```

but with no success. Any Help will be appreciated. brdgs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand that `AlbumVariant` table takes `AlbumId` as a foreign key that means `AlbumId` has to be generated first! You can try this:

```
storeDB.AddToAlbums(album);
storeDB.SaveChanges();   
AlbumVariant av = new AlbumVariant {  
  ... 
  AlbumId = album.Id  //generates after calling the 1st save changes  
}  
storeDB.AddToAlbumVariant(av);   
storeDB.SaveChanges();
```